# Counterexample of Rayleigh Quotient Theorem for specific non-Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let the following non-Hermitian matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
I am asked to find its eigenvalues as well as the quantities
$$a=\mathrm{max}\{\frac{\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}:\ \mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2\}$$
and
$$b=\mathrm{max}\ \mathrm{Re}\{\frac{\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{x}}:\ \mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^2\}$$
and then somehow show that Rayleigh's Quotient Theorem is violated in this case.
So, the characteristic polynomial is $p_A(t)=(t-1)^2$, so the eigenvalue is $\lambda=1$ with algebraic multiplicity of 2. Then, solving $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$ for $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\end{bmatrix}^T$ we see that $x_2=0$ and the eigenvectors are of the form $\mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&0\end{bmatrix}^T$, $x_1\in\mathbb{C}$.

For any real $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2$
$$\frac{\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}}=\dots=1$$
so $a=1$.

For any complex $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^2$
$$\frac{\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{x}}=\dots=1$$
so $b=1$.

Rayleigh's Quotient Theorem (from Horn and Johnson's [Matrix Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521548233) book) says

> Let $A\in\mathrm{C}^{n\times n}$ be Hermitian, let the eigenvalues of $A$ be ordered as $\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq\lambda_n$, let $i_1,\dots,i_k$ be given integers with $1\leq i_1\leq\dots\leq i_k\leq n$, let $\mathbf{x}_{i_1},\dots,\mathbf{x}_{i_k}$ be orthonormal s.t. $A\mathbf{x}_{i_p}=\lambda_{i_p}\mathbf{x}_{i_p}$ for each $p=1,\dots,k$, and let $S=\mathrm{span}\{\mathbf{x}_{i_1},\dots,\mathbf{x}_{i_k}\}$. Then
>
> (a)$$\lambda_{i_1}=\min\limits_{\{\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}\in S\}}\frac{\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{x}}=\min\limits_{\{\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}\in S\text{ and }||\mathbf{x}||_2=1\}}\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}\leq\max\limits_{\{\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}\in S\text{ and }||\mathbf{x}||_2=1\}}\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}=\max\limits_{\{\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{0}\neq\mathbf{x}\in S\}}\frac{\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{x}}=\lambda_{i_k}$$
>
> (b)$\lambda_{i_1}\leq\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}\leq\lambda_{i_k}$ for any unit vector $\mathbf{x}\in S$, with equality in the RHS (respectively, LHS) if and only if $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_{i_k}\mathbf{x}$ (respectively, $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_{i_1}\mathbf{x}$).
>
> (c)$\lambda_\text{min}\leq\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}\leq\lambda_\text{max}$ for any unit vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^n$, with equality in the RHS (respectively, LHS) if and only if $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_\text{max}\mathbf{x}$ (respectively, $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda_\text{min}\mathbf{x}$). Moreover,
> $$\lambda_\text{max}=\max\limits_{\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}}\frac{\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{x}}\text{ and }\lambda_\text{min}=\min\limits_{\mathbf{x}\neq\mathbf{0}}\frac{\mathbf{x}^*A\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^*\mathbf{x}}$$

Now, I don't see which part of the theorem is violated in this case. I cannot find a suitable vector to show this. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For any real $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^2$...

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = 4 \neq 2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I don't see your point. The vector you chose is not an eigenvector of $A$ since its second element has to be zero based on my proof (if I made a mistake there please let me know).

Comment: I've quoted your mistake.

Comment: What that whatever-his-name theorem says: take any matrix $A$ and construct quadratic form $q_A$ on $\Bbb C^n$ from it in obvious fashion, $q_A (x) = |x^t A x|$. Then, *if* $A$ *Hermitian*, when you restrict it to sphere $\{q_{Id}(x) = 1\}$, maximum of $q_A$ on that whole sphere — not on eigenvectors — will be equal to maximal eigenvalue of $A$, and minimum equal to minimal eigenvalue. There's also part about intersections of this sphere with some subspaces, but it's not very relevant. Does it make sense?

Comment: It seems that the theorem you are referring to is precisely the Rayleigh's Theorem I wrote. But, still you haven't explained why your choice of $\mathbf{x}$ (which has to be in the span $S$ of the orthonormal eigenvectors) is valid. For, any $\mathbf{x}=[x_1\ x_2]^T$ to be an eigenvector I have shown that $x_2=0$, by solving the system $A\mathbf{x}=\lambda\mathbf{x}$. So, how can you choose $\mathbf{x}=[1\ 1]^T$?

Comment: $x$'s in statement of theorem are *arbitrary*

Comment: Then can you check if the theorem you are talking about is the Rayleigh's Theorem I wrote? Also do you think that my calculations of the quantities I denoted as $a$ and $b$ are correct? If not, can you show me how I can calculate them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75336/discussion-between-xsnl-and-mgus).

Comment: OK, I am in the chat.